# Upgraded to minitest 5.4.0. Now must* and won't* doesn't work within Minitest::Test subclass, but assert* still works

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have been using the MiniTest that comes with Ruby 2.1 without a problem.  I would subclass MiniTest::Unit:TestCase create a couple methods like 'test_simple', and everything just worked.  I would use Expectations and Asserts without a problem.

I have upgraded Minitest to 5.4.0 using a gem.  Everywhere I use Expectations (musts and wonts) I get a strangle error. Example of the test class.

```
gem 'minitest'
require "minitest/autorun"
require "rest-client"
require "json"
require "pp"
# require './testcase_addins'


class TestUserKey < Minitest::Test

  def test_simple
    data = 0
    assert( data >= 0 )
    data.must_be :>=,0
  end
end
```

When I run this, the assert line passes without a problem, but must_be line throws this error:

```
  1) Error:
TestUserKey#test_simple:
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_operator' for nil:NilClass
    (eval):4:in `must_be'
    user_key_testcase.rb:14:in `test_simple'
```

The strange part is what is the nil:NilClass in the error can't be nil; it's 0.  Even I change the Fixnum to a String, I still get the same error.

If I change the test to a spec test, everything works again.  So I can't use Expectations with in Unit Tests?  IF that is the case, could someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that with 5.4.0 your test class must inherit from MiniTest::Spec in order to use expectations.

I tested this on a new ubuntu machine with ruby 2.1.2 installed via RVM:

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.2
```

This code works with the stock ruby 2.1.2 (no 5.4.0 minitest gem installed, slightly cleaned up from your example code above):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'minitest/unit'
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestUserKey < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_simple
    data = 0
    assert( data >= 0 )
    data.must_be :>=,0
  end

end
```

Running this code works fine.  To reproduce the error listed above, install minitest 5.4.0:

```
gem install minitest -v 5.4.0
```

Now the code fails with "NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_operator' for nil:NilClass".  You now have both versions of minitest installed:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/  # stock ruby version of minitest
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/minitest-5.4.0/        # minitest v5.4.0 installed via rubygems
```

Now that everything is set up, we can dig into what exactly is happening.  The expectations are defined with a call to infect_an_assertion, like this:

```
infect_an_assertion :assert_operator, :must_be, :reverse
```

For 5.4.0 that call happens in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/minitest-5.4.0/lib/minitest/expectations.rb.  It's roughly the same in both versions, it just happens in a different place.

infect_an_assertion is also roughly the same for both versions.  For :must_be it winds up making this call, which is identical between the two versions of minitest:

```
MiniTest::Spec.current.#{meth}(args.first, self, *args[1..-1])
```

They're doing some metaprogramming here, the call at runtime will look more like this since meth is set to assert_operator:

```
MiniTest::Spec.current.assert_operator(...)
```

The important part is MiniTest::Spec.current.  In 5.4.0 this method returns nil, which results in a NoMethodError exception when it tries to call assert_operator on nil.

**In the stock minitest from ruby 2.1.2:**

Here MiniTest::Spec inherits from MiniTest::Unit::TestCase.  TestCase defines the method current and returns a value that was set in the initialize method.  You can see this all happening around line 1303 of ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:

```
def initialize name # :nodoc:
  @__name__ = name
  @__io__ = nil
  @passed = nil
  @@current = self # FIX: make thread local
end

def self.current # :nodoc:
  @@current # FIX: make thread local
end
```

Therefore, when you inherit from MiniTest::Unit::TestCase in your test class with the stock minitest, current is defined as a method and is guaranteed to return a value when the above call to MiniTest::Spec.current is made.  This is why it works in the stock ruby 2.1.2 minitest.

**In minitest 5.4.0**

In 5.4.0, Minitest::Spec inherits from Minitest::Test, which does not define current (nor do any of its parents).  The current method is defined directly on Minitest::Spec.  It simply returns Thread.current[:current_spec]:

```
# line 83 of ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/minitest-5.4.0/lib/minitest/spec.rb      
def self.current # :nodoc:
  Thread.current[:current_spec]
end
```

The value of Thread.current[:current_spec] is set in the Minitest::Spec constructor on line 87 of the same file:

```
def initialize name # :nodoc:
  super
  Thread.current[:current_spec] = self
end
```

The problem is that when your test class inherits from Minitest::Test, the Minitest::Spec constructor never gets called and Thread.current[:current_spec] is never initialized.  That means the call in infect_an_assertion to Minitest::Spec.current returns nil, which results in the NoMethodError you're seeing when it tries to call assert_operator on nil.  The solution is to make your test class inherit from Minitest::Spec so that the constructor is called and Thread.current[:current_spec] gets a value.

Here is a slightly modified version of the original code that works with minitest 5.4.0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

gem 'minitest'
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestUserKey < Minitest::Spec

  def test_simple
    data = 0
    assert( data >= 0 )
    data.must_be :>=,0
  end

end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the [minitest readme](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/README.txt), it seems like the `must` style syntax is a part of the spec syntax, which would require you to use methods like `describe` and `it` instead of defining your own unit test methods.

Comment: But i wasn't with the last version of ruby 2.1 with the builtin Minitest.  That is really what i'm looking for.  Why?